# Moderator diamond missing on community wiki posts

Tags: bug, community-wiki, moderators

On Meta Stack Overflow, [Why was my flag declined? When to use custom mod flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368693/why-was-my-flag-declined-when-to-use-custom-mod-flags), the original question author shows up as "Yvette Colomb" in the regular view, but "Yvette Colomb ♦" in the comments and revision history. The same applies to the answers, both the one by Yvette Colomb ♦ and the one by Undo ♦.

I believe it should show up with the diamond in the regular view too.

---

Screenshot:

[image: Yvette Colomb vs Yvette Colomb ♦]

---

This isn't site-specific: other examples can be found on other sites, such as Interpersonal Meta's [Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site), or the main Stack Overflow's [What good technology podcasts are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there) (Michael Stum ♦'s deleted answer).

Comment: Oh indeed. I did search, but I think it didn't show up because I searched for "community wiki", not just "wiki". I'll leave this question up to perhaps make it easier for others to find.

Comment: Funnily enough I couldn't find it when searching either... then came back to this post and it was in the "related" sidebar here